# Writing input of a user into a file within an if-statement. (python)

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to take the input from the user and put it into a file
within an if-statement. When I run the code, it runs smoothly, but it does not write the input into the names.txt file. Here's the code

```py
if click.confirm('Are you a new user?', default=True):
    user_name = input("Welcome. What's your name? ")
    names_file = open("names.txt", "a")
    names_file.write(user_name)
else:
    print("Welcome back")
```

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: It does not write the input into the names.txt file.

Comment: You need to close the `file writing` stream like `f.close()`

Comment: Are you facing this issue in CMD or IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script simple build on pythin 3.x

```
if True:
    f = open('test.text', 'w')
    f.write('Hello World from python file write')
    f.close()
```